# Instantiate nested objects is messy

Tags: java, android, handler

DISCLAIMER:  I realize I should be doing `Handler.obtainMessage();` instead of instantiating one myself, but this code demonstrates the problem I'm having with java.

I have some code where I am trying to send a message with a string to a handler in android.

I first tried something like this:
`mHandler.sendMessage(new Message().setData(new Bundle().putString("key","value)));`

This obviously didn't work, it says setData args (Bundle) don't match what I've given it (void);

OK, so putString must return void, and I guess setData will return void as well, so this was a bad approach.  I tried breaking it up like so:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key","value");
Message m = new Message();
m.setData(b);
listener.sendMessage(m);
```

This seems like a messy way to do this.
What is the typical way?  If I do this, these objects will lose their reference and be garbage collected on method completion, or should I add m=null; b=null; to this method; or should I assign them null in the handleMessage method?  (I'm not sure how this works in a multithread situation.)

Comment: I think the argument that it's messy or not is one of opinion.  Are they your classes?  If so you could create constructors that take the "key","value" and Bundle arguments?

Comment: Thanks @tom, I guess I assumed it was 'messy' but I don't know why, I assumed there would be an alternative (more streamlined) method.  I guess not, and that will be OK, as a newbie I'm never quite sure I'm not doing something in a ridiculous way.  They are stock android classes, and both are final.

Comment: The code is easy for people to understand.  I'd go for readability over compactness any day of the week!

Answer (score 0):

*nullyfying* those local variables won't hurt, but as far as I know, garbage collector will handle them properly even if you don't. Keep in mind that the memory allocated for those objects won't be released, at least until the method are receiving them as params finish their work.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems like a messy way to do this.

You are certainly welcome to your opinion. When you write your own Java classes, you are welcome to offer fluent interfaces on them, to achieve the coding structure that you first tried.

> What is the typical way?

The one that compiles. So, in the case of `Bundle`, you would use the latter code snippet. When you you write your own Java classes, you are welcome to offer fluent interfaces on them, to allow you to do things more akin to your first code snippet.

> If I do this, these objects will lose their reference and be garbage collected on method completion

As with many garbage-collected languages (C++, Java, Ruby, and Smalltalk, to name four off the top of my head), local variables (`b` and `m` in your latter code snippet) go out of scope when the method returns. In this case, they will not be garbage-collected, because there are other references to those objects... which was generally the point of creating the objects in the first place.

Also note that there is no functional difference between the two snippets of code (if `Message` and `Bundle` offered fluent interfaces to make the first snippet compile). In fact, it would not surprise me in the least if they compiled to the same bytecode.

> or should I add m=null; b=null; to this method

Those will have no effect here.

> should I assign them null in the handleMessage method?

Since those are local variables, they do not exist in your `handleMessage()` method, and therefore you cannot set those local variables to be `null` in `handleMessage()`.

This sort of stuff is covered in educational materials on Java, such as books and courses.

Comment: I know local variables will be GCd after the method returns, but I am just starting with multiple threads and wasn't sure how the reference in the other thread would affect it, thank you for explaining; I couldn't really find exactly that in the tutorials I've been using.

Comment: @nexus_2006: "but I am just starting with multiple threads and wasn't sure how the reference in the other thread would affect it" -- the "chain of custody", if you will, of the `Message` is that first you are holding a reference to it (in the local variable), then you and the `Handler` are holding a reference to it, then just the `Handler` is holding a reference to it, then it is passed to your `handleMessage()` method. Threads do not directly impact GC, though threads that can reach an object will prevent the object from being GC'd until the thread lets go or the thread is terminated.